# c# asp.net calendar refreshes page and drop down list multiplies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Really stupid design I believe but this is the code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Project", "p"));
    bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Training", "t"));
   ....
```

As you can see I set the list item from c# code. Now I have two calendars on the asp.net page. Each time I select a date on it, I notice the drop down list values/items multiple..So for example:

```
1- Training
2- Project
then with selection:
1- Training
2- Project
1- Training
2- Project
```

I think it is something to do with page load placement...what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Project", "p"));
        bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Training", "t"));
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to only insert the items once, *when the page first loads*. Each time you select a date on the calendar, your `Page_Load()` method is being fired again.

Wrap your insert statements in an IsPostBack check, as below

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
   bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Project", "p"));
   bookingTypeList.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Training", "t"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
bookingTypeList.ClearSelection();
```